# Red5 and RTMPS self-signed certificate

Tags: red5, self-signed

I am trying to configure rtmps using self-signed certificate, but when I try to connect via red5pfone I get an error:

```
 *** ServerHelloDone
 NioProcessor-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 890
 NioProcessor-2, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
 NioProcessor-2, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, unknown_ca
 NioProcessor-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
 NioProcessor-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
 [WARN] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmps.RTMPSMinaIoHandler - Exception caught SSL handshake failed.
```

Red5-0.9.1

Red5Phone-R47

I tried to follow the directions from here:
http://gregoire.org/2008/05/26/rtmps-in-red5/ and http://www.cb1inc.com/2007/05/12/creating-self-signed-certs-on-apache-tomcat-5-5/ but it did not give results.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certs are really difficult to use with Flash and should be avoided. I would assume that you are using "localhost", but if you are trying to access this from an external location I would suggest getting a real CA-signed certificate (there are free ones out there) and testing with that on your domain. Versions of Red5, 1.0 or greater have better support for certs, crossdomain, and ip binding; I suggest you start with one of them.