# Red5 RTMPS failed connection with self signed certificate

Tags: red5, self-signed, rtmps

I'm using Red5 1.0.3, and trying to accomplish RTMPS over port 8443, with a self-signed certificate.

What I've done already:

- Enabled RTMPS in conf/red5-core.xml
- Added my self-signed certificate to the keystore and truststore
- Confirmed that the passphrase for the keystore and truststore is correct (this is a test, so the passphrases are the same for the sake of simplicity)
- Resolved the "untrusted certificate" issue by accepting the exception in my browser (using Chrome on Ubuntu)
- Ensured that Red5 was listening on 8443 and the port was connectable

The next roadblock I have is an "empty response" in the browser when trying to connect to Red5.

From the Red5 log:

```
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmps.RTMPSMinaIoHandler - SSL provider is: SunJSSE version 1.7
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.BaseConnection - New BaseConnection - type: persistent
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.BaseConnection - Generated session id: 7DTVIWZ5UXILR
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - startWaitForHandshake - 7DTVIWZ5UXILR
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session opened: 77 id: 7DTVIWZ5UXILR
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session closed: 77 id: 7DTVIWZ5UXILR
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - connectionClosed: 7DTVIWZ5UXILR
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - close: 7DTVIWZ5UXILR
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - State: connect
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: 7DTVIWZ5UXILR with thread: NioProcessor-30
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Stream service was not found for scope: null or non-existant
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.BaseConnection - Close, not connected nothing to do
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Shutting down scheduler
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Scheduler - shutdown: true queued: 0
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Shutting down executor
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Executor - shutdown: true queued: 0
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - IO Session closing: true
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection state: RTMP [state=disconnecting, encrypted=false, readChunkSize=128, writeChunkSize=128, encoding=AMF0]
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - connectionClosed: 7DTVIWZ5UXILR
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-30] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: null with thread: NioProcessor-30
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.net.rtmps.RTMPSMinaIoHandler - SSL provider is: SunJSSE version 1.7
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.BaseConnection - New BaseConnection - type: persistent
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.BaseConnection - Generated session id: UB7GI0V7POCE2
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - startWaitForHandshake - UB7GI0V7POCE2
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session opened: 78 id: UB7GI0V7POCE2
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Get connection on thread: NioProcessor-31
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: UB7GI0V7POCE2 with thread: NioProcessor-31
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - decodeHandshake - state: RTMPDecodeState [sessionId=UB7GI0V7POCE2, decoderState=0, decoderBufferAmount=0] buffer: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=377 cap=1536: 50 4F 53 54 20 2F 6F 70 65 6E 2F 31 20 48 54 54...]
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Handshake init too small, buffering. remaining: 377
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: null with thread: NioProcessor-31
[WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing UB7GI0V7POCE2, due to long handshake. State: connect
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - close: UB7GI0V7POCE2
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - State: connect
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: UB7GI0V7POCE2 with thread: RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Stream service was not found for scope: null or non-existant
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.BaseConnection - Close, not connected nothing to do
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Shutting down scheduler
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Scheduler - shutdown: true queued: 0
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Shutting down executor
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Executor - shutdown: true queued: 0
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - IO Session closing: false
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session closed: 78 id: UB7GI0V7POCE2
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - connectionClosed: UB7GI0V7POCE2
[DEBUG] [NioProcessor-31] org.red5.server.api.Red5 - Set connection: null with thread: NioProcessor-31
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection close future: org.apache.mina.core.future.DefaultCloseFuture@41fb8175
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection is closed
[WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connection not found for UB7GI0V7POCE2
[DEBUG] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#14164738195671] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection state: RTMP [state=disconnected, encrypted=false, readChunkSize=128, writeChunkSize=128, encoding=AMF0]
```

The connection simply closes.
On closer inspection with Wireshark, I discovered an Encrypted Alert (21), which from my understanding means a failed decryption. No hints yet as to why it failed, but it did.

In the browser (flash client), the console outputs

```
POST https://10.32.1.218:8443/open/1 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 10.32.1.218:8443/open/1:1
DEBUG: Flash says: NetworkManager: NetConnection.Connect.Failed
```

After reading [Red5 and RTMPS self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155464/red5-and-rtmps-self-signed-certificate), I proceeded to use a real certificate (from StartCom), but when connecting to Red5 with that certificate, I receive

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

To which I attempted to re-add the cert to the keystore and truststore with -keyalg RSA (to be explicit), but this did not help.

So back to self-signed certificates....for now anyway.

Advice? Perhaps the client does not accept untrusted certificates and times out on the handshake? 
Any new paths to look down would be appreciated.

**Update**

After updating the Flash client, and setting the NetConnection property `proxyType = "best"`, Flash now outputs `NetworkManager: NetConnection.Connect.SSLHandshakeFailed`

**Update II**

I've realized that I added the certificates to the keystore and truststore incorrectly. I had added the keys to the keystores without also adding their private keys.

To do this, I used the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224863/544884)

I also moved away from a self signed certificate to a CA signed certificate. Issues with self signed weren't worth solving for my situation.